# Redis Search: index size 0 after loading all the vectors in redis

Tags: python-3.x, redis, word2vec, word-embedding

I have started exploring the Redis vector search module, I am following this tutorial for Redis vector search:

[Github - RediSearch](https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/blob/master/docs/docs/vecsim-range_queries_examples.ipynb)

But after loading vectors, I'm getting the index size as 0, though the keys exist in the Redis.

I'm using word vectors for a POC.

I am using this code to create the index.

```py
redis_conn = Redis(host = host, port = port)
schema = (VectorField("vector", "HNSW", {"TYPE": "FLOAT32", "DIM": dim, "DISTANCE_METRIC": "COSINE"}))
redis_conn.ft('w2v').create_index(schema, definition=IndexDefinition(prefix=["X:"], index_type=IndexType.HASH))
redis_conn.ft('w2v').config_set("default_dialect", 2)
```

and using this code to load the vectors into Redis:

```
for key in V.keys():
        np_vector = np.array(V[key])
        key = "X:" + key
        client.hset(key, mapping = {"vector": np_vector.tobytes()})
```

where V is a dictionary of keys and vectors.

after this is done, I am checking the size of the index via

```
print("Index size: ", redis_conn.ft('w2v').info()['num_docs'])
```

but this is giving 0 as the result.

I checked the keys in the Redis, and they are present, but I'm not able to perform any query.

Is there any issue in the current code or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
for key in V.keys():
        np_vector = np.array(V[key])
        key = "X:" + key
        client.hset(key, mapping = {"vector": np_vector.astype(np.float32).tobytes()})
```

My guess is that the blob you are sending doesn't match the expected blob size as it was specified in the index definition (32 * `dim`), and therefore the indexing fails.